# Waring’s problem in commutative rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k\geq 2$ be a fixed integer. If $R$ is a commutative, integral, unital ring, the Waring height of an element $r\in R$ is the smallest number of $k$-ths powers whose sum is $r$ (this height can equal $\infty$, when $r$ cannot be written as a sum of $k$-th powers).

Is a simple example known of a ring containing an element whose Waring height is $\infty$ ?

**Edit**  As noted in Doug Chatham’s comment below, the answer is easy when $k$ is even : take $R={\mathbb Z}$, $r=-1$.

Comment: Perhaps there is something I'm not seeing, but doesn't -1 have infinite Waring height in $\mathbb{Z}$ for fixed even $k$?

Comment: @DougChatham :Absolutely. I’ve addeed that easy fact to the OP, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That worked. the [Eisenstein integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) and $k=3.$ We have $$ \omega = \frac{-1}{2} +  \frac{i \sqrt 3}{2},  $$ so that $\omega^3 = 1$ and $\omega^2 = -1 - \omega.$ The ring is all
$$ x + y \, \omega, \; \; \; x,y \in \mathbb Z.  $$
I got
$$  ( x + y \, \omega)^3 = (x^3 - 3 x y^2 + y^3) + 3 (x^2 y - x y^2) \, \omega   $$
which is to say that the $\omega$ coefficient of every cube is divisible by $3.$  The $\omega$ coefficient of every **sum of cubes** is divisible by $3.$ So $\omega$ itself is not the sum of cubes.

Comment: Nice example! I wonder if this can be generalized to other exponents than $3$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, apparently so, although there may be no quick embedding in the complex numbers. This one is just $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1 \rangle$ and can also be written, through the "companion matrix" construction, as polynomials in a certain square matrix.

Answer (score 6):

If $k = p$ is prime and $R$ has characteristic $p$ then a sum of $k^{th}$ powers is a $k^{th}$ power, so every element has Waring height either $1$ or $\infty$. To get the latter it suffices to find an element of such a ring which is not a $p^{th}$ power. A simple example is $x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

**Edit:** And note that this reasoning lifts to characteristic zero: for any odd prime $p$, if $x$ is any element of a commutative ring $R$ such that $x$ is not a $p^{th}$ power $\bmod p$, then $x$ is not a sum of $p^{th}$ powers. For example, $x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a sum of $p^{th}$ powers for any $p$.

(What is an integral ring?)

Comment: An integral is a ring where every element is integral, i.e. a ring without zero divisors http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Integral+ring

Comment: Is this term distinct from "integral domain" because it also applies to noncommutative rings or what?

Comment: I don’t know mathematical English well enough to answer that question.

Comment: It just seems confusing because it's tempting to parse "integral" (when it's not next to "domain") as "integrally closed."

Answer (score 3):

Another example. Let $q$ be a power of a prime, $R=E$ the finite field $E=GF(q^2)$ and $k=q+1$, and $F$ the subfield $GF(q)$. Then we have for all $x\in E$
$$
x^{q+1}=N^E_F(x)\in F.
$$
Therefore any sum of $k$th powers in $E$ belongs to the subfield $F$ and thus the elements of $E\setminus F$ all have infinite Waring height.

Answer (score 1):

How about $k=2$ (actually any even number will do), $R = \mathbb{Q}$, and $r=-2$?

Comment: No need to put this in an answer, the first comment to the OP already stated that.

Comment: The comment had not been posted when I posted my solution.